# How to SSH Out from a Subnet

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables

I have a home networking setup like the figure below (excuse bad drawing). `VM1` is a VPN "router" that redirect all traffics from `VMBR1` to the `WG` (wireguard) interface. I've managed to configure iptables to jump host when SSH from my home network (`192.168.0.0/24`) into `VM1` or `VM2` (`192.168.1.0/24`). This is the iptables configuration in `VM1`:

```
# forward traffics from eth1 to wg interface
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wg -j ACCEPT

# SSH jumping from home network to VM1/VM2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 2222 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:22
```

To this point, it's only one-way SSH, that means I can't SSH from VM2 (`192.168.1.101`) to home devices (say `192.168.0.132`). I tried adding this into the very top, but still unable to SSH

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.101/32 -p tcp --dport 2222 -i eth1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.132:22
```

`ip` output from VM1

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <REDACTED> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s0
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::84de:7bff:feff:6731/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <REDACTED> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s1
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e455:aeff:fe62:7cc1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wg: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.X.X.X/32 scope global sg
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd7d:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip ru
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

$ ip r show table all
default dev wg table 51820 scope link
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto static
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.101
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
local 10.X.X.X dev wg table local proto kernel scope host src 10.X.X.X
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 192.168.0.101 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.0.101
broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.101
local 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
default dev wg table 51820 metric 1024 pref medium
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fd7d:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX dev wg proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fd7d:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX dev wg table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev eth1 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::84de:7bff:feff:6731 dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::e455:aeff:fe62:7cc1 dev eth1 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev eth1 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev wg table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance.
[image: Setup]

*EDIT: My setup is based on this diagram, this should shows the different subnet.*

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you are talking about. What do you even mean "jump host"? `I can't SSH from VM1 to home devices` As per your diagram, VM1 is in the same network as home devices. What "jump host" do you need? As for VM2 and VM3, for home devices to reach them, you need a route on the home devices themselves (or less ideally but more "manageable", on your home router) for `192.168.1.0/24` with the gateway address being VM1 IP configured on eth0. Also you'll need to make sure VM1 route traffics for `192.168.0.0/24` out of eth0, including those from `eth1`.

Comment: Note that DNAT is not a way to make "route exception". The `--to-destination` address is still affected by the routes on the host. And I think you should start with adding `ip a`, `ip ru` and `ip r show table all` outputs on VM1 to your question.

Comment: @TomYan I uploaded another diagram, does that make it clearer?

Comment: It's not the topology / structure of your network isn't clear. The problem is I have no idea why you are messing with DNAT or trying to have "jump host" (whatever that means), because none of them are unnecessary in such setup.

Comment: It's a SSH jumphost (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host). I can't SSH from a one subnet (`192.168.0.0/24`) into another (`192.168.1.0/24`) without jumping through. Now the problem is I can't makes it two-way SSH (`192.168.1.0/24` -> `192.168.0.0/24`)

Comment: I mean, you can indeed avoid additional route on your home network by using DNAT'ing traffics from your home devices  "for VM1" to VM2/VM3, if you wish, but that doesn't avoid the need of correct routing for traffics from VM2/3 or VM1 itself so that they can reach / reply to your home devices. (Nevertheless, your DNAT rule is apparently incorrect anyway.)

Comment: If your filter/FORWARD on VM1 actually has DROP/REJECT as its policy or its "fallback" rule, you will need extra rules to allow corresponding traffics as well (since now WG is not the only interface traffics may need to go out of).

Comment: I don't have any DROP/REJECT policy, but I've updated the post to show the `ip` output as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so apparently for some reason, you would like to use `192.168.1.1:2222` to "represent" `192.168.0.132:22`, even when you can really just `ssh` the latter directly on/from VM2/VM3.

As I mentioned, **either way** you need a correct route (i.e. one with `192.168.0.101` as the gateway) on your home network (either the relevant devices, or the router) for `192.168.1.0/24` so that traffics for the subnet can reach your VMs (instead of being forwarded to your Internet gateway). Note that "traffics" here also include ssh "replies" from your home network to your VMs.

But since apparently you also decided you just want to use `192.168.0.101:some_port` to represent "sockets" on VM2 / VM3, then you can take the alternative of source NAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

or

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.101
```

which will eliminate the need of a route for `192.168.1.0/24` on your home network because traffics from your other VMs to your home network will now appear to be originated from VM1.

P.S. For the record, source NAT in Linux is done in a stateful manner, which means even if you do have a "proper" route for `192.168.1.0/24` on your home network, the source NAT will not prevent replies for the properly routed traffics from having "correct" source IPs (i.e., `192.168.1.x`) when they are forwarded out of `VM1`. It's just that *if* you wish to reach the other VMs from your home network with their own IPs (instead of VM1's IP in your home network), you will need the route anyway, which will render the source NAT unnecessary.

Comment: This seems to achieve what I wanted to do, but wouldn't this also redirect all my non-local (the one that supposedly go out through `wg`) to `eth0` too?

Comment: @Ryan no, as I keep emphasizing, NAT does not change routing. (It at best determines which route is used / relevant, i.e., the case of DNAT)

Comment: Huh, so that's what it means when you say "stateful" in the answer. I'm just not very useful in networking in general, does this "guarantee" that no internet traffics will leaks to `eth0` in all circumstances?

Comment: Not really, "stateful" refers to the fact that NAT rule is not applied to all traffics that are seemingly a  match to the rule, but only "initiating" traffics. For "other" traffics, conntrack takes care of them. It is not really relevant to your concern regarding routing and leak. And I guarantee that if anything leaks, a source NAT rule would never be the reason.

Comment: Gotcha, that's a very interesting fact. Thanks for your patience in answering my questions!

Comment: Hey I got one more question if you don't mind, I just wanted to understand it. Supposedly I changed the SNAT to `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 --destination 192.168.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.101` (note the `--destination 192.168.0.0/24`), this will also do the job. But what truly makes it different from using `-s 192.168.1.0/24` instead? Seems like the `--destination 192.168.0.0/24` is more specifically targeted for local network packets, whereas `-s 192.168.1.0/24` will takes all packets. So I guess it's better to use `--destination` instead?

Comment: @Ryan You can even have both, but I'd  say whether it's "better" is quite subjective. While further limiting the NAT will indeed break communication of leaked traffics, if you really have that much concern of potential leak, you should implement a proper "kill-switch" (i.e., filtering rules).

Comment: I guess you're right. I did indeed added a kill-switch in my `wg` conf. I just worried that messing with nat will bypass that configurations, but seems like I'm worried for nothing. Thanks again for your answer!